# Color Coding Overlapping Text with Macro

Tags: excel, vba, colors

To save quite a bit of time in the Attendance process, I figured it would be a good idea to put together VBA for color coding specific text within cells based off what type of Leave is used. I was attempting to modify a code I had found but the closest I came was this

```
Private Sub AutoColor(Optional ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("B11:O500")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    
    Select Case Right(Target.Cells.Value, 1)
    Case "A"
     Target.Cells.Characters(Start:=Len(Target.Cells.Value), Length:=1).Font.Color = Green
    Case "D"
     Target.Cells.Characters(Start:=Len(Target.Cells.Value), Length:=1).Font.Color = Green
    
    Case "S"
     Target.Cells.Characters(Start:=Len(Target.Cells.Value), Length:=1).Font.Color = Red
    Case "E"
     Target.Cells.Characters(Start:=Len(Target.Cells.Value), Length:=1).Font.Color = Red
    Case "Y"
     Target.Cells.Characters(Start:=Len(Target.Cells.Value), Length:=1).Font.Color = Red
    Case "Q"
     Target.Cells.Characters(Start:=Len(Target.Cells.Value), Length:=1).Font.Color = Red
    
    Case "L"
     Target.Cells.Characters(Start:=Len(Target.Cells.Value), Length:=1).Font.Color = Orange
    Case "I"
     Target.Cells.Characters(Start:=Len(Target.Cells.Value), Length:=1).Font.Color = Orange
    
    Case "W"
     Target.Cells.Characters(Start:=Len(Target.Cells.Value), Length:=1).Font.Color = Blue
    Case "C"
     Target.Cells.Characters(Start:=Len(Target.Cells.Value), Length:=1).Font.Color = Blue
    Case "EX"
     Target.Cells.Characters(Start:=Len(Target.Cells.Value), Length:=1).Font.Color = Blue
    Case "HW"
     Target.Cells.Characters(Start:=Len(Target.Cells.Value), Length:=1).Font.Color = Blue
    
    Case "OT"
     Target.Cells.Characters(Start:=Len(Target.Cells.Value), Length:=1).Font.Color = Purple
    Case "P"
     Target.Cells.Characters(Start:=Len(Target.Cells.Value), Length:=1).Font.Color = Purple
    Case "G"
     Target.Cells.Characters(Start:=Len(Target.Cells.Value), Length:=1).Font.Color = Purple
    Case "B"
     Target.Cells.Characters(Start:=Len(Target.Cells.Value), Length:=1).Font.Color = Purple
     
     End Select
     
 Application.EnableEvents = True
 Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
 Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

The Intersect is to avoid any possibility of recoloring anything outside of the actual days, themselves, but that throws an invalid procedure error; that isn't the main problem, however. The main issue is that there can be cases of multiple types of leave being used (an example being the cell showing as 4A 0700-1100 4S 1100-1530.) This code would color the whole cell based off the first eligible value and I need it to color overlapping strings. In the example I gave, 4A 0700-1100 would need to be green whereas 4S 1100-1530 would need to be red. Here is an example of how the cells are formatted

[image]

Comment: Do all these cases have 12 characters and are these characters the only ones 'to be colored'? Show us more sample data to figure out what to do because in the code you are checking the first character while in the sample you gave the first character is a digit. Shouldn't you check the 2nd character then?

Comment: Time segments can go from .15 to 8 and they would always include the timeframe used. The timeframe will always be in military time

Comment: I wonder if you could start from the first eligible character, offset to the first space to the left of it and then color up to the next eligible character and repeat. I am uncertain if this would throw back an error because of the overlap. Emphasis on Space over Character

Comment: That is 8 as in 8 hours; I did mis-write part of that. Time segments go from .25 hours up to 8 hours. It has never happened before, but someone could theoretically take a different 15 minute segment for every possible timeslot in their shift.

Comment: The longest a string could be is "1.25A 0700-1500" That would be 15 characters, not including any spaces that may occur before the next string. There are many variations on it, but none that would increase the characters

Comment: Ok, that's enough information (for me). Just one more thing: how will you trigger this? By a button or what did you have in mind?

Comment: This will be done via a macro ran through a form control button

Comment: I was wrong, there isn't enough info. I think you should post the sample data (sample data with colors) explaining why the various characters are in a certain color. Also the case statements are indented which isn't standard practice, so you are possibly trying to tell something there i.e. it is confusing: if `E`, then `EX` will never happen or if `W` then `HW` might never happen. But the sample data is crucial.

Comment: I added an image; the code I posted also has every color listed but I will change it off of Index Color to make it easier to tell without reference. The extra indents aren't for anything other than to make it easier for me to keep track of where the colors stop repeating

Comment: `Right(Target.Cells.Value, 1)` can never be (eg) "OT" - you only have a single character.

Comment: That is the only case with an O in it; that can be worked around if the cells it is applied to don't go above row 10 or outside of columns B:O. That and EX are the only ones that can be 16 characters, now that I think about it